# Hazelcast-- Apache Camel integration

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am new to hazelcast and camel.
While creating a map-loader using camel, I am calling camel route within the the "load" method. Although the container shows "dataSyncLoad" container is present, but still while loading data on startup of the application, it gives error listed below.

Hazelcast Maploader

```
        @Produce(uri = "direct:dataSyncLoad")
        private ProducerTemplate dataSyncLoad;

        @Override
        public synchronized DataSyncServiceRequest load(CellDataSyncKey key) {
            DataSyncServiceRequest dataSynchTemplateVO = dataSyncLoad.requestBody("direct:dataSyncLoad",key , DataSyncServiceRequest.class);
            if (null != dataSynchTemplateVO) {
                LOGGER.info("Cache Loaded: {}", key);
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("No data found for the key : {}", key);
            }
            return dataSynchTemplateVO;
        }
```

Map Configuration

```
    <hz:map name="getsToolCcaDatasyncMap" backup-count="0" max-size="100" eviction-percentage="25" eviction-policy="LRU"
read-backup-data="0">
            <hz:map-store enabled="true" initial-mode="EAGER" write-delay-seconds="0" implementation="getsToolCcaDatasyncMapLoader"
/>
    </hz:map>
```

> Could not load keys from map store
>   org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during
>   execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: CellDataSyncKey
>   [locoid=20695, dataTemplate=3, deviceName=CCA]]   at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1379)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:622)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:467)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:133)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:149)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:297)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:327)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   com.ge.trans.loader.cell.cache.mapstore.GetsToolCcaDatasyncMap.load(GetsToolCcaDatasyncMap.java:40)[295:cell-cache-service:2.0.0]
>     at
>   com.ge.trans.loader.cell.cache.mapstore.GetsToolCcaDatasyncMap.loadAll(GetsToolCcaDatasyncMap.java:57)[295:cell-cache-service:2.0.0]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapStoreWrapper.loadAll(MapStoreWrapper.java:143)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.AbstractMapDataStore.loadAll(AbstractMapDataStore.java:56)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.loadAndGet(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:161)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.doBatchLoad(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:134)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.loadValuesInternal(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:120)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.access$100(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:54)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader$GivenKeysLoaderTask.call(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:107)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:67)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:212)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_67]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_67]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_67]     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)[276:com.hazelcast:3.6.5]
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException:
>   No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://dataSyncLoad].
>   Exchange[Message: CellDataSyncKey [locoid=20695, dataTemplate=3,
>   deviceName=CCA]]  at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:47)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:73)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:378)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:346)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:242)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:346)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:201)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:128)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:132)[142:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
>     ... 19 more